# grunt watch kicks off tests but no tests are run

Tags: coffeescript, gruntjs, mocha.js, watch

I've got a grunt task that runs correctly the first time (runs stylus, transpiles the coffee, runs the tests). But when the `watch` task kicks off it runs the `mochaTest:all` task but no tests get run.

Config:

```
grunt.initConfig
    watch:
      coffee:
        files: ['app/assets/src/coffee/**/*.coffee', 'app/assets/src/coffee/*.coffee', 'app/webserver.coffee']
        tasks: ['coffee:dev', 'replace', 'mochaTest:all']
        options:
          nospawn: true
      test:
        files: ['test/calc/*.coffee', 'test/*.coffee']
        tasks: ['test']
        options:
          nospawn: true
      stylus:
        files: 'app/assets/src/styl/**/*.styl'
        tasks: 'stylus:dev'

    mochaTest:
      all:
        src: [ 'test/calc/*.coffee', 'test/*.coffee']
        options:
          reporter: 'nyan'
          timeout: 1000

 ...
 grunt.registerTask "test", [ "mochaTest"]
```

Running the test directly:

```
$ grunt 'mochaTest' 
Running "mochaTest:all" (mochaTest) task
 ...   
264 passing (10 seconds)
```

Ok, so that's working. But when the watch is triggered, no tests are run:

```
Waiting...
OK
>> File "test/dataLayer-test.coffee" changed.

Running "mochaTest:all" (mochaTest) task

  0 passing (1 ms)
```

No tests got run. I must have something configured wrong. What's the problem here? Is it a bug?

Versions:

```
$ npm list | grep grunt 
├─┬ grunt@0.4.1
├── grunt-contrib-coffee@0.7.0
├── grunt-contrib-stylus@0.5.0
├─┬ grunt-contrib-watch@0.5.1
├─┬ grunt-mocha-test@0.6.3
├── grunt-text-replace@0.3.2
```

Edit: per Gilad's suggestion, no difference though:

```
grunt watch --verbose --debug
...

Running "mochaTest:all" (mochaTest) task
[D] Task source: /home/dev/projects/alpha/node_modules/grunt-mocha-test/tasks/mocha.js
Verifying property mochaTest.all exists in config...OK
Files: test/calc/calc-test.coffee, ...
  264 passing (9 seconds)
  5 pending

>> File "test/ui-formulaEditor-test.coffee" changed.

Running "mochaTest:all" (mochaTest) task
[D] Task source: /home/dev/projects/alpha/node_modules/grunt-mocha-test/tasks/mocha.js
Verifying property mochaTest.all exists in config...OK
Files: test/calc/calc-test.coffee, ...
  0 passing (2 ms)
...
```

Comment: run `grunt watch --verbose --debug`. It seems to me like mochaTest running from watch isn't getting the right parameters. Also - nospawn is an old parameter. use spawn.

Comment: @GiladPeleg no change, updated question

Comment: spawn: false or nospawn: true means the watch will run tasks within the same context. I recommend the default, spawn your tasks especially with test suites.

Comment: @KyleRobinsonYoung taking that out completely appears to have fixed it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Removing this:

```
options:        
  nospawn: true
```

(alternately this):

```
options:
  spawn: false
```

Appears to have fixed the problem. Bug report [here](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-watch/issues/194).